# Select Adjacent Tax Parcels by Area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, area, select

I am trying to select for adjacent tax parcels where their total area would be close to a specific value (450 acres). Area is already an attribute of each parcel.

ArcGIS v. 10.3.1

Unfamiliar with Python. Have tried and attempted to research various "select" options and neighbors calculations.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

Create a new field in your feature class called "Acres".

Open the Calculate Field tool.  Select "Acres" as the field to calculate.  In the expression section, put the following: "!shape.area@acres!".

Use the "Select Layer By Attributes" tool to select features that are in your range. An express might look similar to this:  "Acres" > 440 AND "Acres" < 460.

[Add Field Tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-field.htm)

[Calculate Field Tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap)

[Select Layer By Attribute Tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-attribute.htm)